# How do you configure Apache on Windows for SSL?

Tags: windows, apache, ssl

Apache just fails to start with NO error message when we try to reboot it after enabling the code for the ssl module.

NOTE: I was able to use OpenSSL to generate a request and have a legit wildcard certificate in place and referenced in the httpd.conf

Comment: Could you give more information? What version of Apache? What exactly did "enabling the code" entail? etc.

Comment: Any luck? Any more info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache on Windows writes to the Windows Event Log when it fails to start, rather than ErrorLog. Did you check in Event Viewer?